# Django: {{ request.user }} doesn't show anything in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My `view` looks like

```
def done(request):
    """Login complete view, displays user data"""
    ctx = {
        'version': version,
        'last_login': request.session.get('social_auth_last_login_backend')
    }
    logging.info(str(request))
    return render_to_response('home.html', ctx, RequestContext(request))
```

in `template: home.html`, I do

```
 <p>Hello {{ request.user }}</p>
```

But it doesn't print the **user**, just prints **Hello**
also I do user in logs

```
'USER': 'iamuser',
```

What is that I am missing here?

Comment: try to use {{ request.user.username }} in template, also make sure your user is successfully logged in.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have added:

```
django.core.context_processors.request
```

to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in `settings.py`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request).

Comment: Thanks @Timmy, I added it, but still I am not able to see the user, do I have to do anything else?

Comment: You'll also have to restart your web server if you haven't already. Otherwise, that should be it. You don't have any other context variables named 'request' do you? I recommend using the ./manage.py runserver web server which will expose any exceptions (alternatively, set DEBUG = True in settings.py) and also installing the Django Debug Toolbar (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar) which, among other things, will list the context processors used as well as all the template context variables when in DEBUG mode. Hopefully they'll help you track down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The request object is not needed. Templates have access to the user variable. So simply `{{ user.first_name }}` will work.